# Is PHPExcel_Calculation::parseFormula() supposed to support multibyte named ranges?

Tags: phpexcel, multibyte

PHPExcel behaves all fine when reading a file that contains multitbyte strings, but for one case: multibyte named ranges with **parseFormula**.

Regardless of *cliché*'s existence as a named range, the expression :

`PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->parseFormula("=SUM(cliché)");`

results in:

`Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Calculation_Exception' with message 'Formula Error: An unexpected error occured`

I doubt a formula-friendly encoding exists -- html has ';' for instance -- so I guess a workaround is possible using a custom encoding. That is my last resort.

So, is it a known limitation? 
Is there an alternative method to use parseFormula() with multibyte strings?

FYI: this occurs with PHPExcel 1.8.1, 2015-04-30.

Comment: Yes it is supposed to handle multibyte named ranges; if it doesn't do so correctly, then that's a bug in PHPExcel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug confirmed and also present in PhpSpreadsheet.

See bug-report [on PHPExcel's github](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1197).